Is it useful and possible to install Nvidia drivers for an old GPU on a current Ubuntu?
I have an old NB that is  planed to be used as a gaming machine for children. Among others, I plan to install older classics via Steam/Gog such as Portal, Sims2, Anno, NfS underground, ...  So I guess 3D acceleration would be useful.
A Geforce 9650m GT with 1GB (aka G96CM) is installed in the NB.
I have installed xubuntu in the latest LTS version 24.04 with kernel 6.8.
And that's where the problems start!
Via the driver search at Nvidia I found the 340 driver: https://www.nvidia.com/de-de/drivers/details/156190/
But it could not be installed with the install-script. Not even if I ignored the messages about the incompatible kernel.
Then i tried it via the Ubuntu driver management; "sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-XXX". But the oldest driver available there is “460”. And when I install it, I get again the message that the G96CM is only supported up to driver 340.
ben@KidsNB:~$ ubuntu-drivers devices
ben@KidsNB:~$ lspci | grep "VGA" 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G96CM [GeForce 9650M GT] (rev a1) 
ben@KidsNB:~$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall [sudo] Passwort für ben: All the available drivers are already installed.

Therefore I have 2 questions:

Is the proprietary driver even worth it with such old HW, or is nouveau just as good?

What would I have to do to get the Nvidia driver to work?


Best regards and many thanks in advance

nouveau isn't just as good, but maybe you're stuck with it for your notebook.

What happens when you run sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall?

Nvidia-340 driver is available in 20.04 with the original kernel 5.4. You'll need to revert to the original one like this

ben@KidsNB:~$ ubuntu-drivers devices
ben@KidsNB:~$ lspci | grep "VGA"
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G96CM [GeForce 9650M GT] (rev a1)
ben@KidsNB:~$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
[sudo] Passwort für ben:
All the available drivers are already installed.
